# Tamanho máximo para tabelas de banco de dados

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, oracle

Qual pode ser o **tamanho máximo** que uma tabela pode ter? Para ficar mais claro: uma tabela no MySQL, qual o tamanho máximo ela suporta? E no SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL?

Comment: Isso varia conforme o fabricante e a versão. Teria que consultar a documentação de cada um. Algumas versões(os express da vida) limitam número de processadores, tamanho da base ou outras caracteristicas. [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-size-limit.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A maioria dos limites são teóricos. Em cada versão isso pode variar (os dados abaixo podem estar defasados), ainda que agora se tenha tornado raro (talvez ocorra com o PostreSQL que é "baixo" perto dos outros).

Nem sempre é fácil determinar, depende de configurações ou combinação de fatores. Alguns não têm limite de tamanho para a tabela e sim para o banco de dados como um todo. Obviamente que se a tabela atingir esse tamanho não haverá espaço para uma segunda tabela.

- [Microsoft SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) => 524.272 TB
- [MySQL MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/table-size-limit.html) => 256 TB
- [MySQL InnoDb](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html) => 64 TB
- [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/limits002.htm#i287915) => 128 TB
- [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/about/) => 1.6 TB
- [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-technical-specifications/) => 18TB
- [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) => sem limite específico, limite do sistema operacional

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: hum... interessante. Havia pesquisado sobre isso antes, mas não achei os resultados da pesquisa bons, havia muitas diferenças, por isso perguntei aqui devido a confiar nos resultados e soluções aqui postados. Também não sabia que a capacidade dos bancos de dados era tão alta (na minha opinião).

Comment: Acho que seria interessante acrescentar a do firebird  mesmo que ele não tenha perguntado >.<

Comment: @stringnome atendendo a pedidos...