# Quantas tabelas o MySQL aguenta?

Tags: mysql

Bom, o que pretendo fazer é criar uma tabela no meu banco de dados para cada utilizador, agora a minha pergunta é: Quantas tabelas o MySQL aguenta?

Será que se colocar bastantes tabelas o meu servidor não trava ou dá algum bug?

É que o meu site tem perto de 1000 usuários.

O que me recomendam?

Obrigado.

Comment: Recomendo analisar a real necessidade de ter "uma tabela para cada usuário". Quanto a quantidade de tabelas não sei, pois creio que dependa muito da quantidade de leitura e escrita no seu banco de dados. Se for muito grande a transferência de dados vai precisar de mais processamento no servidor.

Comment: Já trabalhei em sistemas com centenas de milhares de usuários, **todos na mesma tabela**, porém em várias linhas diferentes na mesma tabela. O sistema tinha um determinado número de tabelas (umas 40 ou 50), mas cada uma delas era para uma finalidade distinta. Tem certeza que você não está confundindo o conceito de tabela com o conceito de linhas de tabelas?

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139408/101

Comment: @VictorStafusa creio que seja isso mesmo que ele quer. tabelas distintas para cada usuário. Ele parece bem convicto.

Comment: Por exemplo, cada usuário possui os seus itens, para isso ele precisa de ter uma tabela, porque cada linha dessa tabela vai ser um item, Etenderam a ideia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segundo a documentação do Mysql, não existe limite de tabelas ou banco de dados.
O sistema de arquivos subjacente pode ter um limite no **número de diretórios**.

**Engines** de armazenamento podem ter um valor individual, como o **InnoDB** que permite mais de 4 bilhões de tabelas.

O que pode ocorrer é lentidão, devido a quantidade de tabelas existentes, mas limite não existe, dependendo da engine de armazenamento.

*Perceba também que isso é uma péssima prática, claro, depende da aplicação, mas não vejo nenhuma necessidade de fazer isso, vendo que a própria linguagem de programação com uma boa modelagem no BD pode resolver isso de forma mais limpa e eficiente.*

Veja mais em [Limits on Number of Databases and Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/database-count-limit.html)

Answer (score 11):

Não acho que a sua premissa seja uma boa idea.

Imagine que você quer adicionar uma coluna nessas "tabelas por usuário". 1000 usuários significariam, no mínimo, 1000 comandos para executar! O que é um pesadelo tanto em performance quanto em administração.

Se o seu objetivo é separar o conteúdo dos usuários, sugiro:

- Criar uma tabela 'Usuários'
- Para cada tabela a ser separada, inclua uma foreign key para a tabela de 'Usuários'.

Dessa forma, para buscar o conteúdo de um usuário seria simples como adicionar um WHERE:

```
SELECT pedidos.valor
  FROM pedidos
 WHERE usuarioId = 10;
```

Que é bem mais fácil.

Comment: O que seria a FK?

Comment: @Gonçalo Significa Foreign Key - aponta para um PRIMARY KEY em outra tabela.

Comment: @Gonçalo Chave estrangeira (***F**oreign **K**ey*) - É o que é usado para se criar relacionamentos entre tabelas, de forma que valores em uma tabela referenciem linhas em outra tabela. É um conceito fundamental para se entender como um banco de dados funciona e como deve ser usado, portanto recomendo que pesquise sobre isso.

Comment: @Gonçalo, conforme o Mauro comentou. Editei para dar mais clareza.